# Which is the best transaction isolation level for insert row?

Tags: transactions, isolation-level

I need to understand which is the best transaction isolation that I can use to do this 2 things:

1. Save a row in table A
2. Save a row in table B

I know that if I use like transaction isolation `SERIALIZABLE`, it works fine, but I need to know if it is possibile that I can use `READ_COMMITED`, or `REPEATEBLE_READ`. I save only two rows in two different table so I'm not doing READ operation, so I think that READ_COMMIT is the best solution? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a requirement to have the new A and B rows be persisted together and only visible together?  If you're not reading anything and you are OK with A and B not necessarily showing up together, then you don't even need a transaction here.

This is a good related read: https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/01/21/myths-and-misconceptions-about-transaction-isolation-levels/.

Also, the following contradicts what I said before (here, already removed/updated it):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/transaction-isolation-levels?view=sql-server-2017

> **Read Uncommitted:** Transactions are not isolated from each other. If the DBMS supports other transaction isolation levels, it ignores whatever mechanism it uses to implement those levels. So that they do not adversely affect other transactions, **transactions running at the Read Uncommitted level are usually read-only**.

It describes the other states pretty well too.  It sounds like Read committed would be the best here.

> **Read Committed:** The transaction holds a read lock (if it only reads the row) or write lock (if it updates or deletes the row) on the
>   current row to prevent other transactions from updating or deleting
>   it. The transaction releases read locks when it moves off the current
>   row. It holds write locks until it is committed or rolled back.

This would let the delete and the insert you mention in the comment happen safely.

Comment: Humphreys and If the I must do things: 1) delete row in table A from id 2)save a rw in table B, which is the transaction isolation?

Comment: Humphreys So for the first schema (two insert row in two different tables ) I use read uncommited and for the second schema (delete (or insert or update) in the first table and one save operation in the second table I use Read Commited, and in the third schema where there are only select operation on the table A I use READ COMMITTED?

Comment: "transactions running at the Read Uncommitted level are usually read-only" - If you're inserting two rows, I'd use Read Committed or just avoid explicitly defining this so it does what your target DB prefers by default (which will be safe).

Comment: I understand why READ_COMMITED must be use when I save two object ,but how is it possible that for getElement (select) I must use READ UNCOMMITTED if I can read an element and it can